# Android project does not compile in Release Mode when using Kotlin 1.8.0 data objects

Tags: android, kotlin

Despite enabling data object support as per [the Kotlin 1.7.20 document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#improved-string-representations-for-singletons-and-sealed-class-hierarchies-with-data-objects)

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
    languageVersion = '1.9' // data objects
}
```

the project does not build in release mode.

> The feature "data objects" is only available since language version 1.9

What to do?

Answer (score 3):

Just setting the language version is insufficient, you must also enable the language feature explicitly using the following code:

```
kotlin.sourceSets.all {
    it.languageSettings.enableLanguageFeature("DataObjects")
}
```

Similarly to inline classes support.